# React Functional component - UseState with array index

Tags: reactjs

i am new in React. "valueForm" is my state and i'm struggling to assign values to course and institute, those values are dynamic,

i need to get fields as:

```
course: ['MSc','BSc'],
institute: ['PG','Digree']
```

---

```
const [valueForm, setvalueForm] = useState({
  first_name: "",
  last_name: "",

  course: [],
  institute: [],
});

const handlechanage = (event, index) => {
  // console.log('index',index);

  setvalueForm({ ...valueForm, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
};
```

index is from dynamic fields.
I need to perform this inside `handlechanage` function for all fields of `valueForm` state.

Comment: Could you provide the use of `handleChange` function?

Comment: Please add the the part where you are using `handlechanage`

Comment: onChange={(e)=>handlechanage(e,key)}

Answer (score 0):

Try using functional updates as the value is dependent on previous state

```
 const handlechanage = (event, index) => {
  // console.log('index',index);

  setvalueForm((current) => ({ ...curr, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
};
```